# Is there a method which generalises this identity to tensors of arbitrary rank?

Tags: general-relativity

I've come across this funny identity involving the Riemann tensor, which I'm not really sure how to even start proving. 
$$ \nabla_k \nabla_i R^{ik}_{ \ \ \ mn} = 0 $$
The issue in attempting to use normal coordinates here is that this is still a third order derivative equation in the metric, I've tried expanding but it's too complicated to get anywhere with. Is there some symmetry argument we can use here? 
Is there a method which generalises the identity 
$$ \nabla_a \nabla_b X ^ c   - \nabla_b \nabla_a X^c  = R^{c}_{ \ \ d ab} X ^ d $$ to tensors of arbitrary rank? This will help proving this.

Comment: For the torsionless connection this statement seems trivial, due to the identity : $\nabla_\mu g_{\alpha \beta} = 0$. The Riemann tensor is some combination of $g_{\alpha \beta}$ and its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method which generalises the identity 
>   $$ \nabla_a \nabla_b X ^ c   - \nabla_b \nabla_a X^c  = R^{c}_{ \ \ d ab} X ^ d $$ to tensors of arbitrary rank?

Yes. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression) has the desired generalization to a tensor of rank $(r,s)$:

$$\begin{align}
[\nabla_a,\nabla_b]X^{c_1c_2\dots c_r}{}_{d_1d_2\dots d_s}&=
R^{c_1}{}_{eab}X^{ec_2\dots c_r}{}_{d_1d_2\dots d_s}+\dots+R^{c_r}{}_{eab}X^{c_1c_2\dots c_{r-1}e}{}_{d_1d_2\dots d_s}\\
&-R^e{}_{d_1ab}X^{c_1c_2\dots c_r}{}_{ed_2\dots d_s}-\dots-R^e{}_{d_sab}X^{c_1c_2\dots c_r}{}_{d_1d_2\dots d_{s-1}e}
\end{align}$$